# How can I add custom events into jQuery plugin pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

How can I add custom events to namespaced jQuery plugin pattern? I want to add custom events similar to like that:

```
$.myNamespace.myPluginName.trigger( 'myEvent' );
```

Normally, I use pattern like this (Original pattern is [here](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.namespace.plugin-boilerplate.js)):

```
$.myNamespace.myPluginName( '#myDiv' );
```

Here is the pattern:

```
;(function ( $ ) {
    if (!$.myNamespace) {
        $.myNamespace = {};
    }

    $.myNamespace.myPluginName = function ( el, myFunctionParam, options ) {
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$el.data( "myNamespace.myPluginName" , base );

        base.init = function () {
            base.myFunctionParam = myFunctionParam;

            base.options = $.extend({},
            $.myNamespace.myPluginName.defaultOptions, options);

            // Put your initialization code here
        };

        // Sample Function, Uncomment to use
        // base.functionName = function( paramaters ){
        //
        // };
        // Run initializer
        base.init();
    };

    $.myNamespace.myPluginName.defaultOptions = {
        myDefaultValue: ""
    };

    $.fn.mynamespace_myPluginName = function
        ( myFunctionParam, options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            (new $.myNamespace.myPluginName(this,
            myFunctionParam, options));
        });
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery Docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)

Provide Callback Capabilities

What is a callback? – A callback is essentially a function to be called later, normally triggered by an event. It's passed as an argument, usually to the initiating call of a component, in this case, a jQuery plugin.

If your plugin is driven by events then it might be a good idea to provide a callback capability for each event. Plus, you can create your own custom events and then provide callbacks for those. In this gallery plugin it might make sense to add an "onImageShow" callback.

```
var defaults = {

    // We define an empty anonymous function so that
    // we don't need to check its existence before calling it.
    onImageShow : function() {},

    // ... rest of settings ...

};

// Later on in the plugin:

nextButton.on( "click", showNextImage );

function showNextImage() {

    // Returns reference to the next image node
    var image = getNextImage();

    // Stuff to show the image here...

    // Here's the callback:
    settings.onImageShow.call( image );
}
```

Instead of initiating the callback via traditional means (adding parenthesis) we're calling it in the context of image which will be a reference to the image node. This means that you have access to the actual image node through the this keyword within the callback: